# How to convert seconds into hours minutes inside Pivot in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have written a pivot query in sql server 2012. It works fine and it shows the result of usernames under Rows and sum of production hours in seconds under columns. But I need the seconds to be splitted into hours:minutes format. Please help me on query.

```
declare @empid nvarchar(20), @fromdate date, @todate date, @cols nvarchar(max), @query  AS VARCHAR(MAX), @dt varchar(20), @dt1 varchar(20) 

set @empid = 'EC0100'
set @fromdate = '10/01/13'
set @todate = '10/31/13'
set @dt='Exceptions'
set @dt1='Tech Issues'

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(nvarchar(20),c._Date, 101))
         FROM MIS_BM_Calendar c
         where c._Date between @fromdate and @todate and _Day not in
('Sunday')
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
         ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
     ,1,1,'')

set @query= 'select UserName, '+@cols+' from 
(select  e.UserName, c._Date , (SUM(DATEDIFF(SS,0,c.TimeTaken))) As TimeTaken
 from MIS_BM_Users e 
 inner join MIS_Opus c 
 on e.EmpId=c.EmpId 
 where (e.AccountManagerID='''+@empid+''') and c.Category not in ('''+@dt+''','''+@dt1+''')
 group by c._Date, e.UserName
) As SourceTable
Pivot
(
SUM(TimeTaken) for _Date in ('+@cols+')
) As Pvt'

execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a scalar function and converted the seconds to HHMMSS. Then include the function in the main query.

```
ALTER function [dbo].[ConvertSecondsToHHMMSS]
(
@TotalSeconds int
)
Returns nvarchar(20)
As
Begin
declare @hours int, @minutes int, @seconds int, @result nvarchar(20)

set @hours = @TotalSeconds / 3600
set @minutes = (@TotalSeconds % 3600) / 60
set @seconds = @TotalSeconds % 60

set @result =  CONVERT(nvarchar(20),@hours) + ':' + CONVERT(nvarchar(20),@minutes) + ':' +CONVERT(nvarchar(20),@seconds)

return @result
end
```

Main Query:

```
set @query= 'select UserName, '+@cols+' from
(
select  e.UserName, c._Date, dbo.ConvertSecondsToHHMMSS(SUM(DATEDIFF(SS,0,c.TimeTaken))) As TimeTaken from MIS_BM_Users e 
inner join MIS_Opus c on e.EmpId=c.EmpId 
where (e.AccountManagerID='''+@AccountManagerId+''')
and c.Category not in ('''+@Condition1+''', '''+@condition2+''')
group by c._Date, e.UserName
) As SourceTable
Pivot
(
MIN(TimeTaken) for _Date in ('+@cols+')
) As Pvt'

execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 2):

The amount of seconds in a minute and in an hour is constant. 60 seconds in a minute, 3600 seconds in an hour. Pivot query has no impact on this.

Thus, your question becomes how can I convert seconds into hours, minutes and seconds. Since you're on 2012, you have the handy dandy TimeFromParts function and so you can see you need to feed it hours, minutes and seconds

```
WITH SRC (TimeTaken) AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM sys.all_columns AS AC
)
, Proof AS
(
    -- this logic is valid as long as TimeTaken is less than 24 hours
    -- or 86400 (24 * 60 * 60) seconds
    SELECT 
        SRC.TimeTaken
        -- integer division drops remainder
    ,   SRC.TimeTaken / 3600 AS Hours
        -- integer division and modulo operator to keep legit values
    ,   (SRC.TimeTaken / 60) % 60  AS Minutes
        -- modulo to have values 0 - 59
    ,   SRC.TimeTaken % 60 AS Seconds
    FROM
        SRC
)
SELECT
    P.TimeTaken
,   P.Hours
,   P.Minutes
,   P.Seconds
,   TIMEFROMPARTS(P.Hours, P.Minutes, P.Seconds, 0, 0) AS TimeTakenTimeType
FROM
    Proof AS P;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/10727/0)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion however I couldn't implement this inside the pivot. So I created a scalar function and achieved the result. Please see below my answer.